# socket.io - weird behavior while reloading page

Tags: javascript, firefox, socket.io

**Hello everyone,**

I have a very simple javascript web application that connects to a socket.io service.
Everything is working as expected in Chrome, however I experience slightly 
different behavior in Firefox.

What seems to be the issue? Well , it's the disconnect that is being called 
once the client hits the refresh button.

- In Chrome the client's behavior looks as follows:

  - user hits refresh button
  - **applicaiton calls socket.diconnect**
  - page is reloaded
  - client is connecting again.

-

- In Firefox on the other hand it's different:

  - user hits refresh button
  - page is reloaded
  - **applicaiton calls socket.diconnect**
  - client is connecting again.

So the reconnect is called after the page is relaoded not before.

So I'd like to know if there is any workaround so I could make it work as 
it's now working in Chrome. Or it's also possible that there is something missing in my code?

client.js

```
    socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3090',
        { secure: true, query: { uData }, reconnect : true }
    );
    socket.on('disconnect', function (){
            console.log(' [Info] Disconnecting ..');
            socket.disconnect();
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Alex

Comment: I think it's because Fiirefox waits for the response from socket server ..and Chrome does not ,it simply skips the part and the it goes straight to the disconnect part. Now I just need to figure out how to make Firefox not to wait for the answer and execute the callback right away.

Comment: Have similar problem. After page refreshes socket reconnects and then disconnects. This messes up my app.

Comment: @Wracker exactly the same issue i m having, did u find any way to fix this issue? if so , plz share working code e.g and also if its client side fix or server side?